# Downloading a mail attachment to a remote server

Tags: command-line, email, download, remote-access

I recieved a large zip file by mail. And I want to download it to my remote server, for which I have only cli access. What can I do in this situation? I'm not running any mail clients in the remote server. And my local internet connection is not dependable for large file transfers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do** run a mail client in the remote server. You can use `mutt` or `alpine` to connect to the IMAP server and save attachments:

```
mutt -f imap://user@server/INBOX
alpine -f "{server}INBOX"
```